# Deleting an entity without retrieving it first (Entity Framework 4)

Tags: entity-framework-4

I use code like this (described in [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160201152524/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/27/tip-9-deleting-an-object-without-retrieving-it.aspx)) to delete an entity:

```
Category stub = new Category { ID = 4 }; 
ctx.AttachTo("Categories", stub); 
ctx.DeleteObject(stub); 
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

However, this fails when the object with ID=4 is already loaded into the context by some previous operation. Is there any way to check and do the attaching only if there's no such object in the context?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [ObjectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679461.aspx) method, which returns `false` if there is no state entry for the object.

You can get the `ObjectStateManager` from the `ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager` property.

Comment: Correct. +1. Although this wasn't working for me, because (i believe) im using POCO's. In my case i had to use a special overload which constructed an `EntityKey`.